# UPDATE with multiple criteria and multiple rows

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to be able to update a table using one UPDATE statement, but include various criteria in it.  The following code contains a table test_table which holds main_id which can have product_case id's and customer_case id's. I would like to be able to check the table CASETABLE and if theres a 'PC' case or a 'CC' case associated with main_id then update the appropriate fields.

```
UPDATE 
    test_table tt
SET 
    tt.product_case = CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'PC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt_.product_case END,
    tt.customer_case = CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'CC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt.customer_case END
FROM 
    CASETABLE ct 
WHERE 
    ct.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
    AND ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id
```

Obviously this doesn't work if the main WHERE returns 2 rows as each case will try to SET the correct value and then SET its original value again causing a SQL ERROR 21506 (trying to set more than once for same row).  How can I do this without just using two separate UPDATE statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery with conditional aggregation:

```
UPDATE test_table tt
    SET tt.product_case = COALESCE(ct.pc, tt.product_case), 
        tt.customer_case = COALESCE(ct.cc, tt.customer_case)
    FROM (SELECT ct.MAINRECORD,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'PC' THEN ct.ID END) as pc,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'CC' THEN ct.ID END) as cc
          FROM CASETABLE ct 
          WHERE ct.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
          GROUP BY ct.MAINRECORD
         ) ct
    WHERE ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id ND
          (ct.pc is not null or ct.cc is not null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
UPDATE 
   tt
SET 
    tt.product_case = CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'PC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt_.product_case END,
    tt.customer_case = CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'CC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt.customer_case END
FROM 
    test_table tt
    INNER JOIN CASETABLE ct 
    ON ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id
WHERE 
    ct.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
   UPDATE test_table tt
    SET tt.product_case = 
        (SELECT CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'PC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt_.product_case END
        FROM CASETABLE ct WHERE ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id),
    tt.customer_case=(SELECT CASE WHEN ct.TYPE = 'CC' THEN ct.ID ELSE tt_.product_case END
        FROM CASETABLE ct WHERE ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id)
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM CASETABLE ct
        WHERE ct.MAINRECORD = tt.main_id and STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
```